# Kevin Conroy, the voice of the animated Batman, has passed away at 66

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[News article by Decider](https://decider.com/2022/11/11/kevin-conroy-batman-voice-actor-dead-66/)

> Kevin Conroy, who voiced Batman in multiple shows over the years, has died. He was 66.
>
> Conroy’s death was announced by Diane Pershing, the voice of the DC character Poison Ivy, and confirmed by publicist Gary Miereanu, who said the actor had died Thursday (Nov. 10) after a “short battle with cancer.”
>
> “Very sad news: our beloved voice of Batman, Kevin Conroy, died yesterday. He’s been ill for a while but he really put in a lot of time at the cons, to the joy of all of his fans. He will be sorely missed not just by the cast of the series but by his legion of fans all over the world,” Pershing shared on Facebook today.

Comment: Aww, man!  Conroy was THE voice of Batman, as far as I'm concerned.  No one else comes close.  RIP.

Comment: Forever vengeance. Forever the night. Forever Batman. RIP Mr Conroy, and thanks for those memories.

Answer (score 11):

I found this to be a bittersweet tribute to Conroy's journey to becoming the caped crusader.

**Finding Batman, by Kevin Conroy:**
[image: Finding Batman page 1]
[image: Finding Batman page 2]
[image: Finding Batman page 3]
[image: Finding Batman page 4]
[image: Finding Batman page 5]
[image: Finding Batman page 6]
[image: Finding Batman page 7]
[image: Finding Batman page 8]
[image: Finding Batman page 9]

Comment: Hopefully this is not too much for the site. If it is, I can replace the images with the link to where I found the comic: https://imgur.com/gallery/LFZttru

Answer (score 9):

A [worthwhile homage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKzVg.jpg)

[image: Batman loses his voice]

Comment: I can still hear Bob Hastings and Kevin Conroy very clearly in my head when reading this.

Answer (score 7):

> Clark Kent: Good to see you Bruce.
>
> Bruce Wayne: It's been a while.
>
> Clark Kent: You seem to be holding up pretty well.
>
> Bruce Wayne: I could use some of that Kryptonian DNA.
>
> Clark Kent: You'll outlive us all, Bruce. You're too stubborn to die.
>
> Bruce Wayne: [Looks at Terry] What are you smiling at?
>
> Terry McGinnis: Nothing.

*Batman Beyond, episode [The Call, Part I](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Call)*

Jokes aside, I feel like a huge part of my childhood just died. May he rest in peace.